# Optimizing image buffer in C++

Tags: c++, opencv, buffer

I have 3 (their names are right, left, and back) cameras whose frames I synchronized. However, the  performance of the code is not that good and I wanted to get some advice on how to optimize my code.

"Optimization" could be anything. In fact, I would appreciate advice on anything in the code that could be made better. I am new to this kind of programming and just trying to learn.

Explanation of the code:
There are 3 threads that run a busy infinite loop that reads the camera frames. The threads run the start() function of the CaptureThread class. The line `if (camera_.img_buffer->read(frame_))` reads a frame from the camera.

```
class CaptureThread
{
public:
    CaptureThread(const Camera& camera) : camera_(camera)
    {
    }

    void start()
    {
        continue_thread_ = true;
        run();
    }

    void stop()
    {
        continue_thread_ = false;
    }

    void attachBufferManager(const std::shared_ptr<BufferManager>& buffer_manager)
    {
        buffer_manager_ = buffer_manager;
    }

private:
    void run()
    {
        while (continue_thread_)
        {
            if (camera_.img_buffer->read(frame_))
            {
                buffer_manager_->syncAndWrite(camera_, frame_);
            }
        }
    }

    cv::Mat frame_;
    bool continue_thread_ = true;
    Camera camera_;
    std::shared_ptr<BufferManager> buffer_manager_;
};
```

Each CaptureThread attaches itself to the same instance of BufferManager using the attachBufferManager function()

The BufferManager synchronizes these images by bundling them into a std::unordered_map

```
class BufferManager
{
public:
    BufferManager(int buffer_size) : counter_(0), buffer_size_(buffer_size), num_buffers_(3)
    {
    }

    void syncAndWrite(const Camera& camera, const cv::Mat& frame)
    {
        std::unique_lock lock(mtx_);
        counter_++;
        all_img[camera.name] = frame;

        if (counter_ >= num_buffers_)
        {
            if (all_img_buffer_.size() >= buffer_size_)
            {
                all_img_buffer_.pop();
            }
            all_img_buffer_.push(all_img);
            cv_.notify_all();
            counter_ = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            cv_.wait(lock);
        }
    }

    bool read(std::unordered_map<std::string, cv::Mat>& all_img)
    {
        std::lock_guard lock(mtx_);
        if (all_img_buffer_.empty())
        {
            return false;
        }
        all_img = all_img_buffer_.front();
        all_img_buffer_.pop();
        return true;
    }

private:
    std::queue<std::unordered_map<std::string, cv::Mat>> all_img_buffer_;
    std::unordered_map<std::string, cv::Mat> all_img;
    int counter_;
    int num_buffers_;
    std::condition_variable cv_;
    std::mutex mtx_;
    int buffer_size_;
};
```

The infinite loop of the CaptureThread class calls the syncAndWrite function of its BufferManager

```
    void run()
    {
        while (continue_thread_)
        {
            if (camera_.img_buffer->read(frame_))
            {
                buffer_manager_->syncAndWrite(camera_, frame_);
            }
        }
    }
```

The syncAndWrite() stores the camera frame into the unordered_map (key=std::string, value=cv::Mat) and blocks the loop until the BufferManager's `counter_` variable reaches 3.

```
void syncAndWrite(const Camera& camera, const cv::Mat& frame)
    {
        std::unique_lock lock(mtx_);
        counter_++;
        all_img[camera.name] = frame;

        if (counter_ >= num_buffers_)
        {
            if (all_img_buffer_.size() >= buffer_size_)
            {
                all_img_buffer_.pop();
            }
            all_img_buffer_.push(all_img);
            cv_.notify_all();
            counter_ = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            cv_.wait(lock);
        }
    }
```

`camera.name` is a string that is either "right", "left", or "back"

Later, the all_img_buffer of BufferManager is read and displayed

```
while (true)
    {
        if (buffer_manager->read(all_imgs))
        {
            cv::hconcat(all_imgs["right"], all_imgs["back"], all_frame);
            cv::hconcat(all_frame, all_imgs["left"], all_frame);
            cv::imshow("all_imgs", all_frame);
            if (cv::waitKey(1) == 'q')
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Viewing the 3 frames using cv::imshow() results in what feels like a ~10fps video, which is not ideal. Viewing 1 camera at a time feels like ~30fps.

Comment: Can't speak for OpenCV, but I have experience in capturing and processing synchronized video at 250 fps. You want to avoid the following: busy-waiting, polling, halting frames from one camera due to another camera, writing to disk on more than one thread. If you can do it with OpenCV, set up asynchronous callbacks that notify you when a frame arrives. Use a ring buffer to hold frame data. Store frame data for multiple cameras _together_ in memory (_e.g._ make a "super frame"). Write to disk on a single background thread. Avoid compression. Use OS-level I/O routines for performance. BENCHMARK!

Comment: As a side-note, pay attention to your theoretical data rate limits. If these are USB cameras, work out the actual bit rate for a single camera at 30fps or whatever. Then compare that to the maximum bit rate for your USB controller. You might be throttled simply because of this. One possible solution there is to split the cameras onto separate USB controllers (hardware-permitting) to avoid saturating one. Similar data rate considerations should be made if storing to disk, as throughput can be severely limiting. This is a major reason why output should be buffered and decoupled from input.